# Check if SSL Certificate is present or not in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, https, ssl-certificate, afnetworking

I have an API end point which has an SSL Certificate (secure https API). My iOS app bundle also includes that certificate so when I try to reach the API end point, objective C verifies if the certificate matches or not. My implementation of matching certificates works fine.
But I also need to verify if the API provides an SSL Certificate or not.

I am using AFNetworking for matching the certificates, and the place where it verifies the certificate: `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge` does not even gets called when there is no certificate present. Hence the app doesn't verify anything.
I need something to verify in first place if the API has certificate or not, and if it doesn't then the app should not reach to the API end point.